# Implementing a tile-based game

Tags: c++, tiles, data-structure

Which data structure should be best used to store a pile of tiles from which a player can pick a random tile?

Comment: We need more information to give a good answer (more...)

Comment: For example, will you be adding tiles to the structure? Will you be removing tiles from the structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest any container that has [random access (wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_access), for example a plain array, vector, or deque.

```
int tiles[100];
```

or

```
std::vector<int> tiles;
```

This will allow you to select a random element without having to step through the container.

*I have left a comment asking for more information, if more information is added I'll update this answer.*